# De-duplicate for each loop c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a foreach loop that returns something like this:

```
value 1
value 1
value 1
value 2
value 2
value 2
value 2
```

I need to get that list but only the first of each type. So,

```
value 1
value 2
```

below is my code.

```
<div>
    @foreach (var publishedVideo in allVideos)
    {
        <p>@publishedVideo.GetPropertyValue("segment")</p>
    }
</div>
```

How do I de-duplicate the list?

Comment: `allVideos.Distinct()` perhaps? (If your videos implement equality appropriately...)

Comment: `De-duplicate for each loop c# [duplicate]` I love this title.

Comment: @Flater In Soviet Russia, questions about duplication duplicates you.

Comment: @Flater thanks guys, but having already tried the supposed duplicate question, it didn't work. If I understood the answer I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: What output did you get when you tried Camilo's solution?

Comment: Try `@foreach(var seg in allVideos.Select(a => a.GetPropertyValue("segment")).Distinct()) { <p>@seg</p> }`

Comment: @ElliottJames `If I understood the answer I wouldn't have asked the question` We cannot make that call if you don't specify that you've already tried that option. This is why it's important to show your work, rather than merely ask for a solution.

Comment: @mjwills - I got the result I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your class does not implement an equality comparer (hence `Distinct` wouldn't work), you could use this:

```
<div>
    @{ 
        var nonDuplicatedVideos = allVideos.
            .Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue("segment"))
            .Distinct();
    }
    @foreach (var publishedVideo in nonDuplicatedVideos)
    {
        <p>@publishedVideo</p>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Camilo for answering the question. @mjwills -  Cheers for marking question as a duplicate. Although it's a duplicate, apparently the two answers are different. And the answer the 'duplicate' didn't solve my problem. Bravo. Thanks again Camilo

Comment: FYI you don't need the `ToList` here.

Comment: @juharr yes, I know, I just find it more readable with the ToList.